# Visual Basic web application call function from multiple objects

Tags: vb.net

I have a Visual Basic web application where I will have a 5x5 grid displayed on the web page. Each grid box will contain a button. I want to be able to access the button attributes when any button is clicked. I would assume I would create a private function to handle each button click (I would create 25 functions), but I want each private function to call a public function which will receive the object and the grid coordinates.

My buttons on the web pages are called `btn_column1_row1`, `btn_column2_row1`, `btn_column3_row1`, `btn_column4_row1`, `btn_column5_row1`, `btn_column1_row2`, etc.

I want to code the private functions like this:

```vb
Private Sub btn_column1_row1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_column1_row1.Click
    inspectButton(e,100,1,1)
End Sub

Private Sub btn_column2_row1_Click(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_column2_row1.Click
    inspectButton(e,100,2,1)
End Sub

Private Sub btn_column5_row5_Click(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_column5_row5.Click
    inspectButton(e,500,5,5)
End Sub
```

Then, the function `inspectButton` should look something like this:

```vb
Function inspectButton(ByVal e as EventArgs, textvalue, column, row)
    Dim Question as string = Session("question")
    Dim Answer as string = Session("answer")

    if e.text = textvalue then
        e.text = Question(column, row)
    else
        e.text = Answer(column, row)
    end if

    return
End Function
```

Is this the correct way to pass the button object to the `inspectButton` function?

Comment: Pass `sender` rather than `e` if you want the control that caused the event.

Comment: Passing sender worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btn_Click(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_column1_row1.Click, btn_column1_row2.Click, btn_column3_row5.Click, btn_column5_row5.Click, btn_column5_row1.Click 'etc
            inspectButton(sender)
End Sub

Function inspectButton(ByVal btn as Object)
    Dim Question as string = Session("question")
    Dim Answer as string = Session("answer")

    if btn.Text = btn.Text then
        btn.Text = Question(btn.column, btn.row)
    else
        btn.Text = Answer(btn.column, btn.row)
    end if

    return
End Function
```

Maybe this can be a solution... i can't understand the textvalue,column and row parameters passed...

You can handle multiple events with a single sub.